# Exchange 2010 Unified Messaging prerequisites: which versions to use?

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange, prerequisites

The Unified Messaging role in Exchange 2010 has the following prerequisites:

- [Unified Communications Managed API 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4705)
- [Microsoft Speech Platform Server Runtime 10.1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24974)

But these components are obsolete, as the most recent ones (which are also used by Lync Server 2010) are:

- [Unified Communications Managed API 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20958)
- [Microsoft Speech Platform Server Runtime 11.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27225)

The question: does Exchange 2010 Unified Messaging work with these new components, or does it specifically require their previous releases?

This is a new deployment of Exchange Server 2010 SP2, so I'd like to avoid installing already-obsolete components if this is not an absolute requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exchange 2010 (even SP2) installer explicitly checks for UCMA 2.0 and SPSR 10.1; any other installed version causes it to fail.